# loadDataSource issue when changing ViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

My root View is a `PSCollectionView` (https://github.com/ptshih/PSCollectionView).
In this class I have method `loadDataSource`  that loads data from my web service.

```
-(void)loadDataSource {
NSLog(@"Load data source");
NSMutableArray *mainListings = [Utils getPosts:selectedCategory begin:@"0" date:@"0"];
self.waterflowViewData  = mainListings;
[self.waterflowView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating]; //This is when i use pull to refresh to call it.
}
```

This method is called in `viewDidLoad` of the `rootView` like this

```
[self loadDataSource];
```

And in the `pullToRefresh` method like this

```
__weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;
[weakSelf loadDataSource];
```

My problem is when I push a `ViewController` using `self.navigationController` this method `loadDataSource` is being called. It is being called only in these two places I searched. Even when I get back from a 4th `ViewController` to 3rd `ViewController` the 'loadDataSource' is being called (i check with NSLog). Why is that happening cause it makes the app slower and also utilises web service resources.

This is how I push all my `ViewControllers`

```
-(void) addButtonClickEvent:(id) sender{
    LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: If you stick an NSLog before the two places where you call loadDataSource (viewDidLoad and the pullToRefresh) which one is calling it? Specifically, which one is calling it when you are popping the view controllers?

Comment: I was just trying it and it comes from viewDidLoad, I also tried removing it from there and putting it in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear' the same happened.

Comment: viewDidLoad will **only** be called when the VC is loaded for the first time. It def won't be called when you pop the 4th View controller back to the 3rd View controller. If you are getting an NSLog showing viewDidLoad when you pop a VC, then something is wrong with your VC push / pop logic - and I would look there

Comment: I know it isn't supposed to be called, I use only `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];` to push the views and let the navigation controller handle the going back

Comment: just to be clear, when you call popVC on (say) vc4, vc3 is calling viewDidLoad? If that's the case something v. strange is going on! Not sure I can help.

Comment: yes calling viewDidLoad, im letting the navigationController do the popping, I didn't write any code for popping

Comment: What I suggest you do is to NSLog the view controllers on the navigation controller stack (self.navigationController.viewControllers) and make a note of the memory address of each VC. Then in your viewDidLoad look at the memory when a pop happens. From the above, it seems like you are (somehow) creating a new VC when you're popping - and you'll see a new memory address.

Comment: Nice suggestion, Just tried and the memory addresses stay the same of the rootView. Only the popped vc addresses change like it is supposed to :/

Comment: sorry - will have to leave you with that one - good luck

Comment: please show some more code'

Comment: @SamkitJain I also added how i push the view controllers, I dont think there is anymore relevant information

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints in loadDataSource? Then when it gets there you will get a nice stack trace of which function is calling which that you can click through.

Comment: I've tried but I'm not really that good with stack traces

Comment: @Accatyyc you sir are a genius, 1 week I've been suffering with this. The culprit was `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` that strangely was in every `viewWillAppear` . Write the anwers so ill check it as the right answer

Comment: @Elgert Great to hear :) I've added an elaborated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint (click the line number) in your function being called too many times and then run the app. This will give you a nice stack trace of which function is calling which:

[image: Xcode stack trace]

The function in the top is the one where your breakpoint is, and the trace below is each function call leading up to your breakpoint.

The grayed out functions are internal functions, while the ones with dark text are probably functions within your application. Click them and Xcode will show you the code that is calling the next function.

Click the output window (console) and press enter (or type c -> enter) to continue debugging until reaching the next breakpoint.